# Linker error 348: Compilation failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linker

Greetings everyone.  I am hitting a road block on a very strange linker error and I thought I would throw it out here in the community to see if anyone has any thoughts (or better yet has seen it before).

The error is this:
error 348: Compilation failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

The scenario is this:
I have 3 class library assemblies (Lib1, LibCommon, Lib2) and as you might have guessed, LibCommon is referenced by both Lib1 and Lib2.  The error seems to occur when I add a new class to LibCommon and then use it in Lib2 (using it in Lib1 is never a problem).

Environment:
Windows Server 2003
Visual Studio 2008 SP1
.NET 3.5 SP1
C#

Any thoughts?

Comment: C# doesn't use a linker.  Document whether this is a 64-bit operating system. whether you use strong names and what the Target Platform settings are.

Comment: Not exactly true, the C# compiler will take the code down to IL and then the build process will take the IL, create obj files, and then the linker will take the obj files and turn them into assemblies (in my case).  The issue is at the level of the linker so we are past all of the rest of the steps.

As for platform, we are talking about 32-bit (x86).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error by trying to use the `[OnDeserializing]` attribute on a method with the incorrect method signature. Fixing the method signature resolved the error.